# Close WPF PopUp when clicking on Window Title bar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can see that the PopUp dropdown of a combobox gets closed if we click anywhere else in the app. How do I give that feature to my own Popup. I dont want to give a PreviewMouseDown event handler for the RootWindow to solve this issue. Something at the level of my userControl containing this popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Popup StaysOpen=”False“>
```